# Does a road street sign about parking apply before or after the sign in the United States?

Tags: united-states, driving, washington, parking

I wonder whether a road street sign about parking applies before or after the sign. Location: Seattle, Washington, United States.

---

Example: in the picture below, I wonder  whether the  3-minute passenger load only area applies before or after the sign:

[image]

Zoom on the 3-minute passenger load only side:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Passenger loading is behind the sign, pay to park is in front of the sign. In general, signs indicate the end of a parking restriction.

Comment: Thanks, just to confirm, you mean that the passenger loading area is between the passenger loading sign and the pay to park sign?

Comment: No, it's between the loading sign and the parking lot entrance a few feet earlier. There is a sign in front of the restaurant door pointing east, which is where the pay-to-park is